# Why does Facebook's Graph API's oembed_post not fetch Facebook Posts (but videos and images, instead)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Simple task: I want to embed a Facebook post using the Graph API.
Here's my PHP code:

```
    # Sample URL    
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sponsoo/posts/pfbid0vSuL3n1Rgixv1eQeF3M9DY9ytg328kNDKbeAZcrbpK67ydmEZkQsua6reA7kjhqSl';
    $endpoint = '/oembed_post?' . $url;
    $accesstoken = 'mySecretAppAccessToken';

    # Request - usually surrounded by try-catch, but I'm letting it hard-fail to get more error info
    $response = $this->facebook->get(
       $endpoint,
       $accesstoken
    );
```

This request returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A7GxHS046iSG_eRwSZoiz_m"
  }
}
```

You can also simulate the request here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

The strange thing - if I fetch a medium, like a video or a photo (NOT a post), the request works. Any idea what I got wrong?